how to on mouse unblur a image with taildwind or reactjs / typescript
Hello i try multiple solution to when my mouse in on a image it's unblur but i still dont find how i use blur-md to medium blur but when i trop to wrap another librarie inside it's doesnt work
        <img
        src="/assets/images/wall1.png"
        alt="logo"
        className="hidden xl:block h-screen w-1/2 object-cover bg-no-repeat blur-md"
        
        />

i try with other libraries but none of theses are working

Do you want the blur logic to be in JavaScript, or CSS?

can i see both ?

just to see which one is the best

Try to add "blur-none hover:blur-md"
<img src="/assets/images/wall1.png" alt="logo" 
className="hidden xl:block h-screen w-1/2 object-cover bg-no-repeat blur-none hover:blur-md" />


Tailwindcss docs. Blur: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/blur, hover: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states,

With JavaScript


const img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => img.style.filter = "blur(10px)");
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => img.style.filter = "");
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />



With CSS


img.hover-blur:hover {
    filter: blur(10px);
}
<img class="hover-blur" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />




I wanted the opposite but thanks !

Ah, you want it to be blurred by default, and unblurred when you hover? I think you'll manage to make that change yourself :)

using css
img{
   filter: blur(10px);
}

img:hover{
   filter: none;
}

